# Is it possible to transfer ios application from react native to swift native app?

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, swiftui

I have an iOS app published in store, made with React-Native. (it is created by other developer, i'm not the original developer in this project.)
Now i'm refactoring my application into SwiftUI.
Is it possible to change entire project in same package? I want to keep app store page of my application.

I read how to publish applications. I read how to manage app package uri.

Comment: Yes.  Just use the same bundle ID and release a new version.  If your app has saved any data locally you will need to ensure that your new version reads that existing data.  Make sure you test installing your new version on top of the existing version.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, possible.
Keep your bundle identifier same and Increase your app version.

Answer (score 2):

It is completely possible. You need to re-submit the updated app for review and approval by Apple.

Be sure that the *bundle identifier* is the same, otherwise it will be treated as a new app and will not replace the old one on the App Store page.

There are already many examples of companies that have completely changed the codebase of their apps.